# Command line tool that validates YAML file against a JSON schema written in YAML

Tags: command-line, continuous-integration, validation, yaml, schema

I'm looking for a YAML validator that can validate YAML files against a JSON schema written in YAML.

I found Yamale - but this tool does not use the JSON schema standard but its own schema definition.

For VScode, red hat's YAML extension works, but this is only for the IDE. I'm looking for a CLI tool I can run in CI.

Is the best I can do to convert both schema and file to be validated to JSON then validate using a JSON schema validator?